# How to find out the period of fractional part of x

Tags: functions, periodic-functions, fractional-part

I came across this solved example in a book, it says -
 Find the period of the function : $f(x)=\sin(4\pi x)+\{3x\}$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Now I know that if $f(x)$ is periodic with period $T$, then $f(ax+b)$ is periodic with period $\dfrac{T}{|a|}$.

So, period of $\sin(4\pi x)$ is $\dfrac{2 \pi}{4 \pi} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

The book says the period of $\{3x\} = 1/3$. Please explain it to me how to find out the period of a fractional part ?

Comment: Hint: if $f(x)=\{x\}$, then what is $f(x+1)$?

Comment: The period of $x\mapsto \{x\}$ is $1$. Then use the same principle you used for the sine.

Comment: @carlson:  you can use \pi to get $\pi$ and \sin to get sine in the proper font.

Comment: Doesn't $\{y\} = y - \lfloor y \rfloor$, where $\lfloor y \rfloor$ is the "greatest integer" function?  If so, the the period of $\{y\}$ is $1$; it's a "sawtooth" waveform.  So the period of $\{3x\}$ should be $1/3$, since $3x$ hits $1$ three times on $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, $3x$ increases from $0$ when $x=0$ to $1$ when $x=1/3$.  The fractional part then repeats:  it is $0$ at $x=1/3$ and increases to $1$ when $x=2/3$

More formally, write $3x=\{3x\}+3\frac n3$ where $n$ is the largest natural such that $\frac n3 \le x$

Answer (score 1):

From the graph of {x}, you can imply that the period is 1.
So applying the formula for finding period, we get period = T/|a|
=1/(co-efficient
of x)
= 1/3

Comment: Please format your equations in MathJax. This makes it easier for it to be understood.